# script para hacer graficos usando un json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, matplotlib, reporte

estoy investigando para poder realizar algo así como un reporte grafico que se guarde en pdf o algún formato similar y estoy usando python y json. Básicamente es visto varios videos, leí varios artículos pero no estoy encontrando como hacerlo y la verdad soy bastante nuevo en esto.
tengo los siguientes datos en un archivo json que son imaginarios para poder realizar esto que mencionaba

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "name": "ac",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "20%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "63%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acv",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "47%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acf",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "48%"
    },
    {
      "name": "ach",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "error",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "10%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acj",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "43%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acq",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "65%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "20%"
    },
        {
      "name": "bcc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "25%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcx",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "error",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "4%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcn",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "45%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcm",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "35%"
    }
  ]
}
```

he seteado los parámetros para leer y obtener los datos en un archivo py pero no he hecho nada en cuanto a graficarlo, la idea seria tener un grafico de columnas donde por ejemplo según el porcentaje de disk usage de cada servicio me muestre una columna con su porcentaje.
Es esto posible?
Agradezco su ayuda...
Dejo aqui como setee el archivo json

```
#set up json file
def get_data():
    with open('services.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        return data

data = get_data()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este tipo de cosas `pandas` es la librería ideal.

Una vez la tengas instalada podrás convertir datos de diferentes tipos (incluso hojas de cálculo) a tablas que pandas denomina "dataframes". En este caso se puede convertir en dataframe tu lista de nodos (que está en el campo `"services"` de tu diccionario) con algo tan simple como:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data["services"])
```

El dataframe resultante se puede visualizar en la forma siguiente (si usas un Juypter Notebook para ejecutar el ejemplo):

[image: dataframe]

Si no usas Jupyter Notebook puedes imprimirlo en la terminal con un simple `print(df)` y pandas te lo formateará para que se vea alineado, y que no ocupe demasiado (ocultando algunas filas o columnas para ello si fuera necesario):

```
   name version  service                             url disk usage
0    ac   1.0.8  running  https://portal.azure.com/#home        20%
1   acc   1.0.8  running  https://portal.azure.com/#home        63%
2   acv   1.0.8  running  https://portal.azure.com/#home        37%
3   acf   1.0.8  running  https://portal.azure.com/#home        48%
4   ach   1.0.8    error  https://portal.azure.com/#home        10%
5   acj   1.0.8  stopped  https://portal.azure.com/#home        23%
6   acq   1.0.8  running  https://portal.azure.com/#home        65%
7    bc   1.0.8  stopped  https://portal.azure.com/#home        20%
8   bcc   1.0.8  running  https://portal.azure.com/#home        25%
9   bcx   1.0.8    error  https://portal.azure.com/#home         4%
10  bcn   1.0.8  running  https://portal.azure.com/#home        50%
11  bcm   1.0.8  stopped  https://portal.azure.com/#home        35%
```

Una vez lo tienes en un dataframe puedes hacer muchas operaciones con los datos, pero no es este el lugar para explicar todo eso. Deberás mirar la documentación de pandas o ver cualquiera de los cientos de ejemplos disponibles en internet.

Entre otras cosas puede crear gráficas automáticamente con `df.plot()` pero para ello debe contener columnas numéricas y esto no es el caso porque la columna "disk usage" es una cadena en vez de un número.

Naturalmente tienes también funciones para procesar esas columnas y convertirlas en otros tipos, etc. En este caso la conversión podría hacerse así:

```
df["disk usage"] = df["disk usage"].str[:-1].astype(float)
```

Si te das cuenta, ni siquiera he tenido que escribir un bucle. Esa línea opera "a la vez" sobre todos los datos de una columna (en realidad no lo hace a la vez, claro está, internamente pandas iterará sobre los valores, pero desde el punto de vista del código que tú escribes es una sola instrucción y el resultado afecta a todas las filas).

Una vez tienes la columna convertida en `float` ya se puede graficar. Por ejemplo, un gráfico de barras que use como etiquetas para el eje x los nombres de la columna `"name"` se obtendría así:

```
df.plot(x="name", kind="bar")
```

con el siguiente resultado:

[image: Grafica]